# Add class in dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Baled, new SelectList(new [] {"Select Type","Option1", "Option2", "Option3"}))
```

I want to add a css class in the dropdown list.

I have tried this

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Baled, new SelectList(new [] {"Select Type","Option1", "Option2", "Option3"}, new {@class="myclass"}))
```

But it doesn't work

If anyone can suggest me any other better way to display dropdown list will be ok too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have close the bracket at wrong place. you have defined attribute in second paramter of selectlist. actually it should be close first and define in the last parameter of `Html.DropDownListFor`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Baled, new SelectList(new[] { "Select Type", "Option1", "Option2", "Option3" }), new { @class = "myclass" })
```